# Oracle Number Data-Type

Tags: oracle

Just got a little question
when a column got the Datatype Number(6,3)
will this work?

```
1234
1234.23
12345
123456
```

btw google didnt help me :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this won't.

`NUMBER(6, 3)` accepts `6` digits at all with `3` being after the decimal period.

This gives us only `3` digits possible before the period, and, hence, maximal value possible to store is `999.999`

Comment: Easy way to check is
SELECT CAST(1234.23 as number(6,3)) from dual;